# Set secure cookie from weblogic.xml for HTTPS

Tags: spring, cookies, weblogic, setcookie, jsessionid

Cookie is defined into weblogic.xml

```
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-name>A_JSESSIONID</cookie-name>
</session-descriptor>
```

When we use HTTPS connection A_JSESSIONID cookie has no secure status.
Burp security scan found 'SSL cookie without secure flag set' issue.

I can't use

```
<cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
```

because our application could be also used by HTTP.

I tried to do set secure status in Filter

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {

 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

            if(cookies!=null && servletRequest.isSecure())
            {               
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
 logger.debug("set Secure for cookie: " + cookie.getName());
                    cookie.setSecure(true);
                }
            }
...
```

Logger shows A_JSESSIONID cookie. But this doesn't works. It is still not secure.

I have also found an information (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13711/thin_client.htm#SCPRG139):

> WebLogic Server uses two cookies: the JSESSIONID cookie and the
>   _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID cookie. By default, the JSESSIONID cookie is never secure, but the  _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID cookie is always
>   secure. A secure cookie is only sent when an encrypted communication
>   channel is in use. Assuming a standard HTTPS login (HTTPS is an
>   encrypted HTTP connection), your browser gets both cookies.

AuthCookieEnabled are set to true in WebLogic console, but I can not see _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_A_JSESSIONID in my cookie list. Just A_JSESSIONID without secure status.

How could I set weblogic cookie secure dynamically?
Or how I can find _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_A_JSESSIONID?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is my reading on this topic so far -

1. Ensure Administration Console, Domain > Configuration > Web
   Applications > Auth Cookie Enabled is checked (default)
2. List item Enable SSL ofcourse
3. List item

A code like this

```
   workCookie = new Cookie(cookieName,"startValue");
   workCookie.setPath("/");
   workCookie.setMaxAge(10 * 24 * 3600);
   workCookie.setSecure(true);
   response.addCookie(workCookie);
```

now when you access your application in http you dont see this cookie and when accessing over https you will see this cookie.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: 1 - OK; 2 - DONE ; 3 - this code is OK for cookies that are created inside my application, but what about JSESSION cookies, they are created by WebLogic. Can I get cookie from request session in filter, set secure and addCookie to responce? Don't you know about _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_A_JSESSIONID?

Comment: Hey you have not answer correctly here, you have just explained how to create a custom cookie which has nothing to do with the auth cookie.
The issue is that it is not possible to set the JSESSIONID cookie secured in a programmatic way. This cookie is created by weblogic in there internal code

Comment: @nmeylan That is right, I have the same conclusion.So there should be the way to set the cookie Secure by default in WebLogic. But I cannot turn on the feature just by Auth Cookie Enabled in true.

Comment: indeed you have to do it in the weblogic.xml file embedded in your application